# Hiding a div container including php generated content with a script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on a website which has a search engine including advanced search options with filters. I want to hide the filters until a category has been chosen. I'm not sure if that script would even work within the php file, because I also tried the script with simple alerts but it didn't work. I positioned this script at the end of the php file of the advanced search options.

```
<script>

if (document.getElementById("main_cat").value == "-1")
{
document.getElementById("custom_fields").style.display = "none";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("custom_fields").style.display = "inline";
}

</script>
```

`custom_fields` is the id of a div container which displays all the filters with php generated content. `main_cat` is the id of the category, if the value is `-1`, no category is chosen.
I'm working on a website with wordpress if that is important to know.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please make sure you have an element with id `custom_fields` in your `DOM`. Also, I believe you should be having above piece of code in some `event`.

Comment: `==` not `=` ...

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Thanks, I gave a div container the id custom_fields, what do you mean with that I should have the code in some event? I think that the position of the script could be a problem, because I placed it at the end of the php file.

Comment: Like you said you will be displaying the content based on some value change right? you need to accommodate a change event for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a minor semantic error that's causing your script to not function as expected. Also, to achieve the functional behaviour for the `<select>` you will need to do a few extra things, namely, to listen to the `change` event:

```
<script>

// Store variables to elements we want to work with
var mainCat = document.getElementById("main_cat")
var customFields = document.getElementById("custom_fields")

// When the website first loads, hide "custom_fields" by default
customFields.style.display = "none";

// When the user changes the main_cat select, check it's value. If
// value == "-1" then hide custom_fields. Otherwise display custom
// fields as inline
mainCat.addEventListener("change", function() {

  if (mainCat.value == "-1") 
  {
      customFields.style.display = "none";
  }
  else
  {
      customFields.style.display = "inline";
  }

})

</script>
```

As a final note, I saw that the script was actually commented out on your website. Just below the `<!--Script Custom Fields-->`, the script was enclosed in `/* ... */` - remove those to ensure that the script does run, rather than be ignored by the browser.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed it but the script is still not working. I think the script is not executed at all.

Comment: Are you getting any errors logged in the browsers console?

Comment: yes I just saw that, it says syntax error, unexpected token and it refers to the second line in the script code with the {
I could aso send the link to the website if you want to inspect by yourself quickly

Comment: Are you using a button to change the values??

Comment: Hi @robinpurtschert, I just checked your website. Please see updated answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @DacreDenny Thank you so much! this works like a charm! Just another thing, you have any idea how we could do it if we want that the category of the current website is automatically chosen?

Comment: Hey you're welcome! You mean that the category is preselected based on the URL? ie if the visitor is at http://www.travelmarketdirectory.com/category/adventure/, then the category is pre-selected to 'adventure' ?

Comment: Hey, yes exactly! Is that difficult to do? I'm not sure how to read the url

Comment: Sure, this would be better answered in a separate question though - if you'd like to send me a link to a new question I'd be happy to help :-)

Comment: here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049267/preselecting-a-value-based-on-url-with-javascript