# preselecting a value based on URL with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a website which has a search engine including advanced search options with filters. I want that the category based on the url is chosen so the related filters will be displayed. For example if the visitor is at domain.com/category/adventure, then the category is pre-selected to 'adventure'. I'm not exactly sure how to read a url.

```
<script>

var mainCat = document.getElementById("main_cat")
var customFields = document.getElementById("custom_fields")

// When the website first loads, hide "custom_fields" by default
customFields.style.display = "none";

// When the user changes the main_cat select, check it's value. If
// value == "-1" then hide custom_fields. Otherwise display custom
// fields as inline
mainCat.addEventListener("change", function() {

if (mainCat.value == "-1") 
{
  customFields.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
  customFields.style.display = "inline";
}

})

</script>
```

Possible values for the mainCat are: adventure, culinary, day-tours and so on. I want these values to be selected based on the url (domain.com/category/adventure... domain.com/category/culinary..)
customFields is the id of a div container which displays all the filters with php generated content. mainCat is the id of the category, if the value is -1, no category is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preselect the category of your `<select>` element, you could extract the category from the current `location` of the browser (this contains the URL), and then update the value of your `<select>` element accordingly:

```
<script>

  var mainCat = document.getElementById("main_cat")
  var customFields = document.getElementById("custom_fields")

  // When the website first loads, hide "custom_fields" by default
  customFields.style.display = "none";

  // When the user changes the main_cat select, check it's value. If
  // value == "-1" then hide custom_fields. Otherwise display custom
  // fields as inline
  mainCat.addEventListener("change", function() {

  if (mainCat.value == "-1") 
  {
    customFields.style.display = "none";
  }
  else
  {
    customFields.style.display = "inline";
  }

  })

  //[ADDED]

  // Extract category from current url
  const category = location.pathname
  .split('/') // Break pathname to array of strings, split by '/' characters
  .filter(function(item) { return !!item; }) // Remove any empty strings from array
  .splice(-1); // Get last string (your category) from array

  // Update value of select element to current category
  document.getElementById("main_cat").value = category;

</script>
```

#### UPDATE

Based on the CSS and DOM structure of the website, these adjustments to the code should achieve what you require:

```
<script>


    // [ ADDED ]
  function updateCategoryFilters(category) {
    // Reset visiblitiy of all fields
    for(const node of document.querySelectorAll('#custom_fields .custom-field-cat')) {
      node.style.display = "none";
    }

    if(category) {

      category = category.toLowerCase()

      // If category is valid, set visiblitiy of fields for that category
      for(const node of document.querySelectorAll('#custom_fields .custom-field-cat-' + category)) {
        node.style.display = ""; // [ UPDATED ]
      }
    }


  }

  var mainCat = document.getElementById("main_cat")

  // When the user changes the main_cat select, check it's value. If
  // value == "-1" then hide custom_fields. Otherwise display custom
  // fields as inline
  mainCat.addEventListener("change", function() {

    // [ UPDATED ]
    updateCategoryFilters(mainCat.value)
  })

  //[ADDED]

  // Extract category from current url
  const category = location.pathname
  .split('/') // Break pathname to array of strings, split by '/' characters
  .filter(function(item) { return !!item; }) // Remove any empty strings from array
  .splice(-1); // Get last string (your category) from array

  // [ UPDATED ]
  // Update value of select element to current category
  updateCategoryFilters(category);

  // [ UPDATED ]
  document.getElementById("main_cat").value = category;

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem now is that, the Select option which has the value -1 is overwritten. The category name is chosen in the list but it is not really selected. So now it is just displaying the category name but not really acting as it would choose it from the list and the select option which shouldn't be an option value can be selected. I tried it with document.getElementById("main_cat").selected or with document.getElementById("main_cat").options but that didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: So the category gets selected, based on the URL, but the filters for the pre-selected category are not shown?

Comment: Yes and also the the select category (-1 value) can be chosen.

Comment: Can you please send a link to the page causing problems?

Comment: travelmarketdirectory.com/category/adventure/ it is updated here with the script

Comment: When I visit, the filters for adventure seem to be shown which is what I would expect? Setting the 'selected' seems to be a problem also - remove that.

Comment: Alright I removed it. No all the filters of the categories are shown when the page loads, if you re-select another category there are less filters.

Comment: Hi @robinpurtschert just updated answer - does this work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for updating it and taking your time. I removed category = category.toLowerCase() because it got an error and since it's all lower case already. The filters according to the category in the url are now displayed, but it's not selected in the category field. Also some elements got screwed over, not exactly sure why that happened. I've updatet the site again so you should be able to see it.

Comment: You're welcome - just updated, ` node.style.display = ""; ` and ` document.getElementById("main_cat").value = category;` - see answer above. Does this work for you?

Comment: yes, without your help I would've never managed to get there! I really appreciate that you took your time

Comment: you're more than welcome - all the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location:

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname);
```

You can then break apart the path by splitting on `/` character, then populate the fields as you walk through the elements of the path.